# Azure Blob Storage with SAS Token

Tags: azure, go

I'm trying to upload a file to Azure Storage Account as Blob and I have a client provided by this `"github.com/Azure/azure-storage-blob-go/azblob"` package. As I saw in documentation there should be possibility to communicate with Storage using `SAS Token` creating anonymous credential with

```
credential := azblob.NewAnonymousCredential()
po := azblob.PipelineOptions{
    Log: pipeline.LogOptions{
        Log: func(s pipeline.LogLevel, m string) {
            log.Tracef("pipeline message: %s", m)
        },
        ShouldLog: func(level pipeline.LogLevel) bool {
            return level <= pipeline.LogError
        },
    },
}
pipeline := azblob.NewPipeline(credential, po)
```

However, I don't see an option to pass `SAS Token` which I receive from other service after I ask for access.

I also tried do it 'manually' using Azure Storage Account REST API, so my URL was like `https://servicename.blob.core.windows.net/containerID/BlobID?sasToken...` but all I get was 400, 411 and 501 HTTP codes depending on request header.

For example with

```
req.Header.Add("Accept", "*/*")
req.Header.Add("Accept-Language", "en-US,en;q=0.5 --compressed")
req.Header.Add("Accept-Encoding", "gzip, deflate, br")
req.Header.Add("content-type", "application/octet-stream")
req.Header.Add("x-ms-version", "2019-02-02")
req.Header.Add("x-ms-blob-type", "BlockBlob")
req.Header.Add("x-ms-client-request-id", "someID")
req.Header.Add("Connection", "keep-alive")
req.Header.Add("Content-Length", "512000")
req.Header.Add("Transfer-Encoding", "gzip, chunked, deflate")
```

I receive 400 code with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Error>
    <Code>MissingRequiredHeader</Code>
        <Message>
            An HTTP header that's mandatory for this request is not specified.
            RequestId:someId
            Time:2020-02-14T13:47:58.8383371Z
        </Message>
    <HeaderName>x-ms-original-content-length</HeaderName>
</Error>
```

Adding `x-ms-original-content-length` header changes nothing.

The funny fact is that it only happens when I try it in Go code. When I tried any REST Client it was working with these headers.

Summarizing, my need is to put a file into Azure Storage Account as a blob and the second solution which should simply work, does not work, and first one is not completed because I don't see the way to pass `SAS Token`. What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So in the 1st case the problem was that SAS token is passed nowhere in this package. It should be added to URL later on during url creation like:

```
URL, err := url.Parse(blobURL + "/" + containerName + "/" + blobName + "?token as query"
```

And in the second case everything was about `Content-Length` which is not changeable from Header side. It's automatically set during `http.NewRequest(...)` but it must be one of following types `*bytes.Buffer`, `*bytes.Reader` or `*strings.Reader`. Otherwise it's 0. However `http.NewRequest(...)` accepts `io.Reader` as body, so it will compile with everything implementing `io.Reader` interface like `*os.File` but it will not set `Content-Length` which is required in case of Azure Storage Account. When I switched to one of three given types I listed above it started working.